# How to get around CVXPY's DCP constraints?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, python, mixed-integer-programming, cvxpy

I am trying to use CVXPY on a mixed-integer program. One of my constraints is of the form

$$y = \begin{cases} g(x) & f(x)\geqslant m\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

for *affine* functions $f$ and $g$. My construction is $y=\mathbb{I}_{\{f(x)\geqslant m\}}\cdot g(x)$, where I can linearize the indicator variable $\mathbb{I}_{\{f(x)\geqslant m\}}$.

This is convex because $y$ is always convex (either affine or constant). But the DCP ruleset allows no multiplication. Therefore, CVX raises exceptions. Is there any way to get around it?

Any help/correction is appreciated!

Comment: Is the sign for $y$ in other constraints always positive? Otherwise the final problem is still not convex. Use a binary variable $z_i$ and a big-M constraint that allows $z_i$ to be $1$ if $f(x) < m$. Then you can relate $y$ to $g(x)$ with another big-M constraint.

Comment: Have you _proven_ convexity? I'm not seeing it. But the answer to the question is. You don't "get around" CVXPY's DCP constraints. They are a fundamental and necessary component of how the software works. If you can't write your problem in compliance with them, then CVXPY cannot solve your problem, _even if it is convex_.

Comment: As a counterexample of OP's claim of convexity, let f(x)=x, g(x) = -x+1, and m=0.  This function is neither convex, nor concave, nor continuous.